# Datepicker stopped working

Tags: jquery-ui, datepicker

I was hopping someone could check my code to give me a suggestion why my datepicker code has stopped working properly.

```
(document).ready(function() {
 $('#datepicker').datepicker( {
 onSelect: function(date) {
    var urlLoad = 'http://www.website.com/embed/calajax'+(date);
    $("#calendar-results").slideUp(function() { 
        $("#calendar-results").load(urlLoad, function() {$("#calendar-results").slideDown();}); 
    }); 
},
dateFormat: 'yy/mm/dd',
minDate: '0'
  });
  });
```

Comment: what problem are you having and what have you tried already to fix it?

Comment: Hi Geoff when I click on the calendar date the calendar div slides up and then stops instead of sliding down to reveal the hidden calendar-results div.

Answer (score 0):

Other than a missing `$` in front of `(document).ready`, which I am guessing is your typo rather than bug, the only place is most likely to go wrong is the URL you're loading.

Are you trying to load a URL that is on a different host than your website? If that's the case, you may be violating the [Single Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy), which states:

> The policy permits scripts running on pages originating from the same
>   site to access each other's methods and properties with no specific
>   restrictions, but prevents access to most methods and properties
>   across pages on different sites.

To test this, you can try to change the URL to one that resides on your own website and see if it loads. If it does, that is probably the case.

For hosts that you do not have administrative access to, you generally have two workarounds:

- iframe
- [server side proxy](http://jquery-howto.blogspot.com/2009/04/cross-domain-ajax-querying-with-jquery.html)

Comment: Okay, thanks. I just wanted to check the code was correct before investigating other options. The linked url is on the same website so that is not causing the issue but it could be the code on the actual embed url that is causing the issue.